# Git between multiple projects

Tags: git, synchronization

I have multiple projects with directory structure like this:

```
/application/
/images/
/js/
/css/
/system/
index.php
.htaccess
```

Project specific files are in application folder, and "engine" stuff is in others`(system/, css/, index.php, ..)`. Now i'd like to sync my system files, which are the same to all projects, but still will be edited. So how to sync `images, js, css, system, index.php, .htaccess` between multiple projects with GIT?

I'm new to git, but my first thought is to make master(empty) project, without application folder, and af i'll switch from project a to b, then first i'll push a to master project and then pull it to b. And maybe doing it via php. RIght now i have made a php script which i'll include to my every project and it doest the sync, but it has no versioning and is quite slow. I'm using cookie to store last used project by browser and if that cookie changes, then sync all projects. I guess i'll can to the same with `git` and `exec()`.

Is there any better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Git submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979167/git-submodule-update/1979194#1979194) (See [Pro Git book](http://progit.org/book/ch6-6.html)) might help with:

- a parent repo with all your common data
- a submodule repo called application, with your applciation specific data in it